# Number of query values and destination fields are not the same OLEDB

Tags: c#, ms-access, oledb, oledbcommand

I getting an error while i'm trying to insert data to my DB. 
This is the error.

> "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.'".

```
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata],[Idteam],[NumeAgent])" +
        "Select @f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg,team.[id] from team where team.[Email]=@email,@agent";


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f", materialSingleLineTextField16.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l", materialSingleLineTextField15.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", materialSingleLineTextField14.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ph", materialSingleLineTextField13.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add", materialSingleLineTextField6.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cnp", materialSingleLineTextField1.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ser", materialSingleLineTextField3.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@n", materialSingleLineTextField2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", gender);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cui", materialSingleLineTextField4.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@j", materialSingleLineTextField5.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pd", richTextBox2.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@te", bunifuDropdown1.selectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prov", bunifuDropdown2.selectedValue);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@reg", DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH: mm:ss"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", Form1.Email);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@agent", NumeAgent);
```

In DB (clients) i have 17 columns + id (but the `id` is auto increment).
What am I doing wrong?

[clients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptWOB.png)

[team](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KRAKJ.png)

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata],[NumeAgent],[Idteam])" + "Select @f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg,[Firstname]+' '+[Lastname] from team where [Email]=@email,team.[id] from team where team.[Email]=@email";
```

Comment: `[NumeAgent]` has no corresponding insert value.

Comment: Bug is here: `team.[Email]=@email,@agent", `@agent` column value is specified after `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @AlexK. the value is taken from a function.

Comment: You can't put an autoincrement field in an INSERT statement. This would be simple in MSSQL, not sure the best way in MS Access. You may need to use a DataTable with a new row and then use a DataAdapter to Update(), then your DataTable will have the new id populated. Hopefully you can google a better way with MS Access.

Comment: I don't put the auto increment into insert statement.

Comment: Then i misunderstood, apologies. You have 17 columns defined but only setting 16 of them, like the error says.

Comment: Mno, i have 17 + the id, it will be 18

Comment: I count 17 columns and 16 parameters. Is the code you posted correct? You do not count the id, that is not part of insert when it is autoincrement.

Comment: Ok. i don't count the id so.. there will be 17 columns: that is 15 parameters and two selections

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your INSERT statement like this:

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata],[Idteam],[NumeAgent])" +
    "Select @f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg,team.[id],@agent from team where team.[Email]=@email";
```

Note, I have moved the `,@agent` part from the end of `WHERE` clause to the end of `SELECT` field list.

However, I'm not sure your overall idea is correct. If you are selecting values to be inserted from the `team` table, why to also specify them as Command parameters?

Comment: i was trying something like this, without parameter: cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO [clients]([Firstname],[Lastname],[Email],[Phonenumber],[Address],[CNP],[SeriesCI],[NumberCI],[Sex],[CUI],[J],[Personaldescription],[Temperament],[Provenance],[Registerdata],[NumeAgent],[Idteam])" +
                "Select @f,@l,@e,@ph,@add,@cnp,@ser,@n,@sex,@cui,@j,@pd,@te,@prov,@reg,[Firstname]+' '+[Lastname] from team where [Email]=@email,team.[id] from team where team.[Email]=@email";

Comment: @Daniel, you can't specify any additional columns to select like `team.[id]` AFTER you've put `where [Email=@email]`.

Comment: and how can i do that.. i mean resolve the error. i had to put the first name and last name to clients from team table.. if I delete that name and surname from select and leave the one with the selected id, it work.

Comment: @Daniel pls add your DB schema description to question and description of what you are trying to achieve too. So, only first and last name columns should be fetched from the `team` table but the rest of columns to be inserted into `clients` should go from C# code, is that correct?

Comment: Ok, i add some pictures, and yes the c# code is correct.